# Generic interface inheritance castings

Tags: c#, .net, generics, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Currently, I'm facing up with a generic interfaces inheritance problem:

```
interface IParent<T> {
    R Accept<R>(IParentVisitor<T, R> visitor);
}

interface IChild<T, TKey> : IParent<T> {
   R Accept<R>(IChildVisitor<T, TKey, R> visitor);
}
```

I've also created these `Visitor` interfaces:

```
interface IParentVisitor<T, R> {
    R Visit(IParent<T> parent);
}

interface IChildVisitor<T, TKey, R> : IParentVisitor<T, R> {
    R Visit(IChild<T, TKey> viz);
}
```

Implementations:

```
class ParentVisitor<T> : IParentVisitor<T, MyResultClass> {
    MyResultClass Visit(IParent<T> parent) {
      return //...;
    }
}

class ChildVisitor<T, TKey> : IChildVisitor<T, TKey, MyAnotherResultClass> {
    MyAnotherResultClass Visit(IChild<T, TKey> child) {
      return //...;
    }
}
```

Up to now, everything seems to be right. However, guess this situation:

```
static void Main() {
    IList<IParent<MyT>> interfaces = new List<IParent<MyT>>();
    interfaces.add(new Parent<MyT>());
    interfaces.add(new Child<MyT, string>());
    interfaces.add(new Child<MyT, int>());
    interfaces.add(new Child<MyT, TimeSpan>());
    //...

    //(!!*!!)
    foreach (IChild<MyT, string> stringChild in interfaces.OfType<IChild<MyT, string>()) {
      ChildVisitor stringChildVisitor = new ChildVisitor<MyT, string>();
      var result = stringChild.Accept(stringChildVisitor);
      //...
    }

    //(!!*!!)
    foreach (IChild<MyT, int> intChild in interfaces.OfType<IChild<MyT, int>()) {
      ChildVisitor intChildVisitor = new ChildVisitor<MyT, int>();
      var result = stringChild.Accept(intChildVisitor);
      //...
    }

    //and so on up to infitiny types in C#...
}
```

I think it's a non-viable way to get what I want.

What I want to get is to use a `ChildVisitor` on whichever `IChild<T, *>`, where `*` is whichever type. I don't know if I've explained so well.

Something like that:

```
//(!!*!!)
foreach (IChild<MyT, *> asterisckChild in interfaces.OfType<IChild<MyT, *>()) {
  ChildVisitor asterisckChildVisitor = new ChildVisitor<MyT, *>();
  var result = asterisckChild.Accept(asterisckChildVisitor);
  //...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really care what is `TKey` when accepting child in your `ChildVisitor`?

Comment: I think you mean, if `TKey` is used for `ChildVisitor.Visit` implementation? Yes.

Comment: Reflection can help, but do you really want to go this way? `foreach(var it in interfaces) foreach(var face in it.GetType().GetInterfaces()) if(typeof(IChild<,>).IsAssignableFrom....` ..not sure about the last one, but that would be horror to write

Comment: I think that I using a non-best-practive approach to design this behavior... However, I don't quite to figure out how to get it...

Comment: Your design is quite compicated (probably overcomplicated) and I don't see how to do what you want with this design without reflection. Probably you should look at simplifying it.

Comment: How are you even expecting to implement that generic Accept<R>? I think you are overcomplicating things. Do you have something more concrete in mind? I will go less-generic first, try writing the same using object first.

Comment: @firda could you provide me an answer providing some extra helping code around your approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
IList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["key"] = "value"
});
list.Add(new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    ["key"] = 123
});
list.Add("just for the test");

foreach(var it in list)
{
    foreach(var face in it.GetType().GetInterfaces())
    {
        //1. Filter out non-generic interfaces
        // (following GetGenericTypeDefinition() would throw exception otherwise)
        if (!face.IsGenericType)
            continue;

        //2. Filter out anything that is not IDictionary<,>
        if (typeof(IDictionary<,>) != face.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            continue;

        //3. Filter out anything that is not IDictionary<string,>
        var generic = face.GetGenericArguments();
        if (typeof(string) != generic[0]) //note: consider IsAssignableFrom instead
            continue;

        //4. Invoke the method
        var valueType = generic[1];
        var method = face.GetMethod("TryGetValue"); //note: needs to be more specific if overloaded

        //don't know how you want to choose R for the Accept<R>
        //method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(R) });

        var arguments = new object[] { "key", null };
        method.Invoke(it, arguments);
        var value = arguments[1];

        //5. Do something with the result
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
}
```